# Adjust physics to speed up/slow down?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

So I'm working on a Unity game that is essentially a WarioWare clone, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the rigidbody physics to stay consistent with the changing speed of gameplay. For those who don't know what WarioWare is, here's a link: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3VRTgMWVsc). You can see that the games get faster and faster, which for fixed updates is simple enough to reflect, but I'm not sure how to modify the built in physics to keep up. Is there something I can modify to do this for me? Do I need to write my own physics engine with a fixed update? Any suggestions are appreciated. Apologies if this is a simple fix, I'm not very good with physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming something like

```
Time.timeScale = 2;
```

should work?

Comment: That seems like it would do the trick. Does that affect timers too? Like does a 3 second timer still measure 3 seconds, or is it effected by the timeScale?

Comment: What timer are you using?  If you're using something like a C# Timer, then no, it shouldn't.  But if you are using Unity 3D's Time class, then most likely yes. http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html

Comment: Excellent, that's all I needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

If it is the problem of acceleration, you can adjust the gravity.

In tab, Edit >> Project Settings >> Physics.

And you can control it in script dynamically.

```
Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, -9.81 * 10, 0);
```

Comment: If gravity appears to be too strong/weak, it usually means your scene scale isn't 1 unit / metre. Changing scale is usually quite painless.